# Filling C array with pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

The following function is supposed to fill a two dimensional array with floats increasing by 0.5

```
void MatrixFill(float *pf, float x, int rows, int columns, FILE *fp) {
    int i, j;
    printf ("\n***\tBegin MatrixFill\t***\n\n");
    fprintf (fp, "\n***\tBegin MatrixFill\t***\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
          *(pf + i + columns ) = x;
          x += 0.5;
        }
    }    
    printf ("\n***\tEnd MatrixFill\t***\n\n");
    fprintf (fp, "\n***\tEnd MatrixFill\t***\n\n");
}
```

However, I'm not sure what goes in my "filling statement." (`*(pf+stuff)=x;`)

Any help with pointers/ array filling would be great.
Thanks!

Comment: Well, it's `(pf+i+j*rows)` but I'm not very good at explaining.

Comment: There is no 2D array in your code.

Comment: i think he has just pasted a function in the program @Olaf

Comment: @Olaf, there is..a 2D array is basically a 1D array with col x rows cells.

Comment: @ThunderWiring: "there is..a 2D array is basically a 1D array". So there is **no** 2D array! If you calculate manually the index, it still is a 1D array. Likely because OP did not know how to properly pass a 2D array to a function.

Comment: @Olaf: Ok...if that's what you meant, then yes, i agree with you. And aside from the pain in calculating the indices, you achieve the same functionality in both.

Answer (score 1):

this is were you got the mess: `(pf + i + columns ) = x` it should be: `*(pf + i + j * rows)`

**Why is that?**

First, you must see that each row passes through all the columns:

```
     col1|col2|col3
     ----+----+----
row1     |    |
     ----+----+----
```

Now, you see if you want to get to row number x, you must pass through all the columns x times!

**Generally Speaking**

in each 2D array `arr[COLS][ROWS]` where COLS and ROWS are the total numbers of columns and rows consequently, `arr[i][j] = arr[i + j * COLS] = arr[j + i * ROWS]`